# What is the correct term for these 'progress circle' designs in UX?

Tags: java, android, statistics, visualization, user-experience

[Progress Circle Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhNUX.jpg)

1. What is the correct name given to the 'progress circle' design in UX?

Click on the above link "Progress Circle Design" to view the image.

I want to create and use these circles to represent statistics on a dashboard for an Android app that I am creating for a businesses. Typical statistics that will be represented by these circles are total sales, average sale per month, total quotes etc.

2. How can I create these circles?
3. How can I code theses circles in the back-end to reflect the latest statistics and make the circles move to reflect an increase or decrease?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a progress bar.
You can read the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar).